# Display woocommerce widgets sidebar from right to left side

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am new to WordPress theme customization. I am using a theme with woocommerce. when i navigate to the products page click on some item for details it show the woocommerce widgets on right side. I am trying to place that side bar on the left side by changing css. It is working but i am facing this issue.

Before changing css add to quote button working fine.

[image: before css]

After changing css add to quote button stop working.

[image: after css]

Changes in css

```
.with_aside .sections_group {
     width: 77%;
     float: right;
}
.with_aside .four.columns {
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
}
```

Changing css through inspect element

[image: css]

Kindly help me what i am doing wrong.

**Edited**

[URL](http://kakabawa.com/index.php/product/marvel-grill-pan/)

Comment: can you share website URL?

Comment: @DevKiran question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following CSS

```
.column.one-second.summary.entry-summary {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
```